# Horizontal "Revealing" Nav Bar non-functional

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a navigation bar that reveals nav links when the user hovers over a p element. 

The idea is to have the border of the p element expand to the end of the page,

and reveal said nav links.

The issue that I have is that when I move the mouse off of the word within

in the p element, the border moves back to it's original position.

So essentially the nav links would dissappear because their appearence is triggered by the p element being hovered over.


So my question is, how can I get the p element's borders to stay expanded

while I go to select a link ?

Thanks in advance for any and all help/advice.

The HTML:

```
<nav>
<p>Navigate:</p>

<ul id="inner">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a id="yourcomp" href="#">Your Comp</a></li>
 <li id="spec"><a href="#">Spec Spec</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

The CSS

```
nav p {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.6em;
font-weight: 100;
color: #333333;
padding-top: 17px;
padding-left: 7px;
height: 50px;
border: 4px solid #4a4a4a;
border-top: none;
border-bottom: none;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
width: 60px;
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 1s;
}

nav p:hover {
width: 98%;
}
```

(For the sake of keeping this post from being too long, I did not add the css for the ul and li)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just put the `ul` inside the `p` (and make a `div` out of it, since `p` means "paragraph" which it actually isn't). Then hovering over the list items will still be hovering over you container, it stays expanded.

To hide the list of items while the menu is not expanded, you can easily apply `overflow: hidden;` to the container, so whatever does not fit in is not being displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your replay ! I'll try that and see what happens

Comment: Thanks, your idea about nesting the ul within the p, (which I change to a div). That works amazing. However, I'm still not able to get the ul, or the li's to only appear when I hover of the div.